# Identifying an element across pageloads

Tags: javascript, hash

I'm not the sure title of this question is the best, but hopefully this explanation will do a good job of making clear what I'm trying to do. It's 4AM, so plesae forgive and confusion I pass on to you.

Basically what I would like to do is identify if an element that has been selected by the user shows up again on any page of the site. What this is used for is to implement "don't show me again" notices without having to maintain a huge database on the server side for which user hid what notice, and also allow dynamically generated notices to be created.

Giving every notice a unique identifier manually would make dynamic notices impossible, and so a dynamic solution is needed.

The idea I have is to generate a hash of the notice, using something simple to turn the text of the notice into a tidy little hash that can be efficiently stored in `localStorage` without taking up massive amounts of memory if a large number of notifications are used (or if those notifications contain a lot of text).

Obviously, things like MD5 and SHA-1 are immediate candidates, since they are widely used and there are many example implementations in JavaScript to make up for the fact that such functions are not native.

But they seem kind of overkill to me. Every implementation I have seen defines at least a dozen helper functions to get the job done, and I don't like having code I don't understand being used. Besides, I don't need cryptographic strength, I just need a quick and simple hash.

I've come up with the following:

```
function hash(str) {
    var l = str.length, i, out = 0;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) out = (out<<1)^str.charCodeAt(i);
    return out;
}
```

After some testing with a handful of values, this seems to generate reasonably good hashes. It's clearly consistent: the same input will produce the same output.

What I really would like to know is this: **is this a usable hash function**? By that I mean, am I at high risk of collisions by using this hash function?

---

After it being pointed out that `<<` does not rotate, merely shift and discard overflow, the function is now:

```
function hash(str) {
    var l = str.length, i, out = 0;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) out = ((out<<1)|(out&0x80000000?1:0))^str.charCodeAt(i);
    return out;
}
```

This basically implements bit rotation since I don't think there's a built-in operator for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a few samples and it appears not to be very good, because strings longer than 32 chars with the same ending give the same results.

```
console.log(hash('Hello world. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'));
console.log(hash('Something entirely different. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'));
```

For me this yields `721528210` in both cases.

I think this is because you keep destroying bytes by shifting them with <<, while at the same time, the XOR ^ is pairwise. Any letter will change the current 32 bytes, but those will all have been destroyed 32 characters later.

Comment: Ah, because the `<<` doesn't rotate, of course. Makes perfect sense. Okay, is there a rotating version of `<<`, or do I have to implement that myself with: `out = ((out<<1))|(out&0x80000000 ? 1 : 0))^str.charCodeAt(i)`?

Comment: I can't find one but I found most Google results on Javascript operators don't even list `^` so there might be one hidden somewhere...

Comment: Updated the question with the new function. Thanks for pointing out this oversight of mine.